# Bootstrap: Navbar shrink on scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like the logo and nav-links to be shrunk when the page is scrolled. At the moment, the logo is too big on the sticky nav. I have tried adding this JS code -

```
$(window).on("scroll touchmove", function () {
  $('#navbar').toggleClass('tiny', $(document).scrollTop() > 0);
});
```

with the following CSS but it did not work....

```
.header.tiny {
    height:40px;
    background: #aaa;
}
```

I am new to Web Development, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I have attached a snippet of the code...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-main sticky-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img class="logo" src="logo.jpg"></a>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownCabling" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Phone Systems   <i class="fas fa-phone"></i></a>


          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownCabling">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Business Phone Systems</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat 6</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat 6a</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownCabling" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Lines & Calls   <i class="fas fa-phone"></i></a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownCabling">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat 5</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat 6</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat 6a</a>
          </div>
```

Comment: Please include *all* of the relevant code. You don't have an element wtih class `header`.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you lot.

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function(e) {
 if(window.scrollY > 0){
   $('#navbar').addClass('tiny');
 }
 else{
   $('#navbar').removeClass('tiny');
 }
});
```

```css
.navbar, .navbar-brand svg{
  transition: 400ms;
}
.tiny{
  padding: .25rem 1rem;
}
.tiny .navbar-brand svg{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-main sticky-top navbar-dark bg-dark" id="navbar">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" class="d-block" viewBox="0 0 612 612" role="img" focusable="false"><title>Bootstrap</title><path fill="currentColor" d="M510 8a94.3 94.3 0 0 1 94 94v408a94.3 94.3 0 0 1-94 94H102a94.3 94.3 0 0 1-94-94V102a94.3 94.3 0 0 1 94-94h408m0-8H102C45.9 0 0 45.9 0 102v408c0 56.1 45.9 102 102 102h408c56.1 0 102-45.9 102-102V102C612 45.9 566.1 0 510 0z"></path><path fill="currentColor" d="M196.77 471.5V154.43h124.15c54.27 0 91 31.64 91 79.1 0 33-24.17 63.72-54.71 69.21v1.76c43.07 5.49 70.75 35.82 70.75 78 0 55.81-40 89-107.45 89zm39.55-180.4h63.28c46.8 0 72.29-18.68 72.29-53 0-31.42-21.53-48.78-60-48.78h-75.57zm78.22 145.46c47.68 0 72.73-19.34 72.73-56s-25.93-55.37-76.46-55.37h-74.49v111.4z"></path></svg>
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" >
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownCabling" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Phone Systems   <i class="fas fa-phone"></i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownCabling">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Business Phone Systems</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat 6</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat 6a</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownCabling" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Lines & Calls   <i class="fas fa-phone"></i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownCabling">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat 5</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat 6</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat 6a</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
   <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   </p>
   <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   </p>
   <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   </p>
   <hr>
   Last Line...
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers! I will give this a go :)

Answer (score 0):

use this for  5 secs time in shrinking :

```
   $("body").scroll(function() {
                        $('#navbar1').animate({
                            height: <<required height>>
                        }, 5000);
                    });
```

and add

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-main sticky-top" id='navbar1'>
```

Comment: Thanks, will give this a go!

Comment: @JamesSkinner did this worked??? give it a green tick!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Hello I thinks it will ask to your problem.

```html
<nav id="my-nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-main sticky-top heavy">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
   <img class="logo heavy-logo" id="my-logo" src="./logo.jpg"></a>
   </a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" >
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
         <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownCabling" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Phone Systems   <i class="fas fa-phone"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownCabling">
               <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Business Phone Systems</a>
               <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat 6</a>
               <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat 6a</a>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownCabling" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Lines & Calls   <i class="fas fa-phone"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownCabling">
               <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat 5</a>
               <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat 6</a>
               <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat 6a</a>
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
<div class="container"></div>
<style>

.little{
   height: 150px;
}

.heavy{
   height: 200px;

}

.little-logo{
   height: 30px;
}

.heavy-logo{
   height: 50px;
}

.container{
   height: 2000px;
}

nav{
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   border: solid 1px;

}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onscroll = function(ev) {

    if (window.scrollY > 0) {
        document.getElementById("my-nav").classList.remove('heavy');
        document.getElementById("my-nav").classList.add('little');
        document.getElementById("my-logo").classList.remove('heavy-logo');
        document.getElementById("my-logo").classList.add('little-logo');
    } else {
       document.getElementById("my-nav").classList.remove('little');
       document.getElementById("my-nav").classList.add('heavy');
       document.getElementById("my-logo").classList.remove('little-logo');
       document.getElementById("my-logo").classList.add('heavy-logo');
    }
};

</script>
```